# Access 2013 Main Form unable to connect with Subforms

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I have build a query that rescues the information from a form and its 2 subforms. When i run the query it seems like the query doesn't recognize the master and child fields. Becuase it comes out empty, with no results after the Form is submitted. 
I have defined the master and child fields in the subforms. So i'm wondering if maybe i'm defining something wrong in the query. My key field is ProjectID.

This is the SQL of my query:

```
SELECT tblGI.ProjectID, tblMS.methodstate, tblMS.methodstatepic,         tblMS.eqrecomend, tblMS.scheduleest, tblKF.WorkDepth, tblKF.MaterialSoilInfo, tblKF.MaterialSoilType, tblKF.MaterialShredStrenght, tblKF.MaterialDensity, tblKF.MaterialRockSize, tblKF.SorroundingSoilInfo, tblKF.SorroundingSoilType, tblKF.SorroundingShredStrenght, tblKF.SorroundingDensity, tblKF.SorroundingRockSize, tblKF.Landscape, tblKF.[Level of Current], tblKF.BackfillingIssues, tblKF.Visibility
FROM (tblGI INNER JOIN tblKF ON tblGI.ProjectID = tblKF.ProjectID) INNER JOIN tblMS ON tblGI.ProjectID = tblMS.ProjectID
WHERE (((tblGI.ProjectID)=[Forms]![frmGI]![ProjectID]) AND ((tblGI.Service1)=[Forms]![frmGI]![CboService]));
```

this is my subform one statement: 
**tblKF subform**

```
SELECT tblKF.WorkDepth, tblKF.MaterialSoilInfo, tblKF.MaterialSoilType,   tblKF.MaterialShredStrenght, tblKF.MaterialDensity, tblKF.MaterialRockSize, tblKF.SorroundingSoilInfo, tblKF.SorroundingSoilType, tblKF.SorroundingShredStrenght, tblKF.SorroundingDensity, tblKF.SorroundingRockSize, tblKF.Landscape, tblKF.[Level of Current], tblKF.Visibility, tblKF.BackfillingIssues, tblKF.ProjectID
FROM tblGI INNER JOIN tblKF ON tblGI.ProjectID = tblKF.ProjectID;
```

and this si my subform 2 statement: 
**tblMS subform**

```
SELECT tblMS.*
FROM tblGI INNER JOIN tblMS ON tblGI.ProjectID = tblMS.ProjectID;
```

I've looked over the code many times, any ideas or sugestions?

Comment: What is the main form and what are the sub form names?  Can you elaborate a bit more in the question please.  THanks.

Comment: Have you checked the combo output, its the same as the table, i.e. ID in the table ID not display text from combo...

Comment: yes, it does. I have attached the sql statement for the subforms,